# sql: exclude rows if at least one row within it isn't in the list

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have the following simple table

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | L1 | X |
| U1 | L5 | X |
| U2 | L2 | X |
| U3 | L2 | X |
| U4 | L4 | X |
| U4 | L6 | X |
| U5 | L7 | X |

when I execute the statement

```
select COL1 
from table t 
where t.COL3= 'X' 
  and t.COL2 in ('L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4');
```

Result:

```
U1
U2
U3
U4
```

My desired result is

```
U2
U3
```

The U1 and U4 should be filtered out because one of their COL2 contains an element which is not in the list.

Is it possible to achieve it in a SQL statement?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but it seems like a very strange requirement. Is this a real business use case or is this just an assignment from school?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full example of how to achieve what you want using a simple aggregate function:

```
create table test (col1 text, col2 text, col3 text);

insert into test values ('U1', 'L1', 'X');
insert into test values ('U1', 'L5', 'X');
insert into test values ('U2', 'L2', 'X');
insert into test values ('U3', 'L2', 'X');
insert into test values ('U4', 'L4', 'X');
insert into test values ('U4', 'L6', 'X');
insert into test values ('U5', 'L7', 'X');
```

```
select
  col1
from (
  select 
    col1,
    -- aggregate all occurences for each value in col1 and see if any is missing, if so this will be false
    bool_and(col2 in ('L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4')) as has_value
  from test 
  where col3 = 'X'
  group by col1
) agg
where has_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE temp TABLE test102 (
    col1 text,
    col2 text,
    col3 text
);

INSERT INTO test102
    VALUES ('U1', 'L1', 'X'),
    ('U1', 'L5', 'X'),
    ('U2', 'L2', 'X'),
    ('U3', 'L2', 'X'),
    ('U4', 'L4', 'X'),
    ('U4', 'L6', 'X'),
    ('U5', 'L7', 'X'),
    ('U2', 'L2', 'X');

(
    SELECT
        COL1
    FROM
        test102 t
    WHERE
        t.COL3 = 'X'
        AND t.COL2 IN ('L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4'))
EXCEPT ALL (
    SELECT
        COL1
    FROM
        test102 t
    WHERE
        t.COL3 = 'X'
        AND t.COL2 NOT IN ('L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4'));
```

except all return duplicates, except distinct remove duplicates.